# Counting Distinct words AND average time in Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, count

I'm working on analysing some text from a Twitter API using pandas. This will eventually be visualized.

For reference
`df.head()`  of my dataset
is:

```
Count   User    Time    Tweet
0   0   x   2022    ✔️Nécessité de maintien d’une filière  dynam...
1   1   x   2022    Échanges approfondis à #Dakar avec le Premier ...
2   2   x   2022    ✔️Approvisionnement en #céréales &amp; #engrai...
3   3   x   2022    Aujourd’hui à Tambacounda, à l’Est du Sénégal,...
4   4   x   2022    Working hard since 2019 to reinforce EU #auton...
```

I'm looking to return the distinct word count with the average time of the tweet where the word was used in.

Right now, I've been getting the distinct word count of my dataset using `df.Tweet.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()`.

This is useful, returning:

```
the                        1505
de                         1500
to                         1168
RT                          931
of                          906
                           ... 
africain,                     1
langue                        1
Félicitations!                1

Length: 18071, dtype: int64
```

**However, I want to also analyse text usage over time.**

I'm not super experienced so I'm wondering if there is a way to use a function such as df.groupby() to sort this result by time? Or, is there a way to modify my original function to add a column to my results that includes average time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get the words, [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the Time, then perform a [`groupby.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) to get the count per Year:

```
out = (df['Tweet']
 .str.extractall('(\S+)')
 .droplevel('match')
 .join(df['Time'])
 .groupby('Time')[0].value_counts()
)
```

*NB. if you want to exclude non-letters/digits from the words, use `(\w+)` in place of `(\S+)`.*

Output:

```
Time  0                  
2022  à                      3
      #Dakar                 1
      #auton...              1
      #céréales              1
      #engrai...             1
      &amp;                  1
      ...                    1
...
```